# Cached image still grow memory usage on rotation

Tags: android, caching, memory, memory-leaks

im aware about the Drawable memory leaks at Android. I saw lot of guides and im trying a custom cached Drawable.

what i did to test:

```
public class myApp extends Application {
    public static HashMap<String, Drawable> test_svg_drawables = new HashMap<>();
...

 public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
     ...
        test_svg_drawables.put("i1", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_svg_image1));
        test_svg_drawables.put("i2", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_svg_image2));
        test_svg_drawables.put("i3", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_svg_image3));
        test_svg_drawables.put("i4", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_svg_image3));
    }
```

at my Activity onCreate (Kotlin):

```
imageView1.setImageDrawable(test_svg_drawables.get("i1"))
imageView2.setImageDrawable(test_svg_drawables.get("i2"))
imageView3.setImageDrawable(test_svg_drawables.get("i3"))
imageView4.setImageDrawable(test_svg_drawables.get("i4"))
```

as everybody is saying, since im using cached Drawables, it should grow memory only on first create and than mantain the same memory usage BUT this is not what really happens, look this memory monitor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmqzx.png)

why its still growing while im rotating the screen?

from 40mb(first create) to almost 110mb (after some rotations)

i already had some memory leaks in older version and im trying to avoid it again

should i worry about it? (STILL the same 110mb 10minutes after i took the picture and i closed the activity with finish)

ps1: using svg_drawable (imported from AndroidStudio -> New -> Vector Asset)

ps2: i will have landscape variant (this was only a demo without it)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest you not to use static references, please just do not use them. They hold the memory references to the component even if the components to which they are attached to is destroyed in users perspective. For example when you use static member to hold things they will hold the data they have through the lifetime of the process and also they implicitly holds the reference of the class they are member of. So basically when configuration changes static members will not allow garbage collector to clean the memory of the component which is no longer used by the user as user is using the new instance of that component. So basically in `Application` there is a method [`onConfigurationChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) which you should override according to the requirements and you should go through [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) also. Best of luck.

Comment: Nice tips thx. But how to avoid drawable leak since they are bound to active and when u destroy activity, they stay in memory? Look my example, even if its cached in same variable, it keep leaking. So is the drawable? Bitmap created from drawable that is leaked? and how to effectivilly DESTROY it on acticity.finish?

Comment: Only thing I can think of to avoid such problem is first do not use `Application` class for the things such as storing information because of the reason mentioned at http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/ and now do not pass android context to the static members as I did explained in the answer above. So basically you should do move the stuff that you did in `Application` class to appropriate activity or any application component without using the static references. When you avoid this thing you will see healthy memory stats.

Comment: If this thing helped you please consider upvoting my answer or accepeting it. It would be really helpful for me. Thaks.

Comment: try to create a simple activity with no static but loading a Drawable, open and close it many times, you gonna see that the memory usage do not decrease =(

Comment: Can you provide some idea or psudo code of activity so that I can understand where  you are wrong at.